# React - How to login a user through Django backend?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, authentication

**Backstory**

as a learning exercise, I first built a website using only Django; then, I learned React (still in the process) and I was moving the frontend part in it and using Django only as backend. I have them on 2 different addresses 127.0.0.1:3000 and 8000.

Now, I created all sort of API where React can fetch and send data to Django in order to read and manipulate the DB, the Login it is mainly the only thing that I'm still missing. I think this is probably due to the fact that I let Django handle all the things for the login, doing minimal work.

**The situation**

So, at the moment, in Django the login works this way:

*settings.py*:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/users/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/users/'
```

*url.py*:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/user_login.html'), name='user_login'),
```

*user_login.html* (shorted):

```
{% block body %}
{% if form.errors %}
        <p>
            Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.
        </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />

    {% if next %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    {% else %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'registration:main_page' %}" />
    {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

All of this works. But I have little clue what's happening behind, and that's bad. Generally, I try writing my own code in order to understand stuff, but this time I wasn't able too, and adopted this 'standard' solution found all over the web.

**The question**

How do I implement this, in React?

What I tried to do for now is:

1. Creating a Login Page
2. Creating a form and submit button
3. Sending data with a POST request over Django
4. Have Django receiving the login data through an API
5. Used the login function in Django, using the credential received (return successful login)

From now on, I have the user and password in Django, but I simply don't know how to handle them. Moreover, I saw several issue in the process.

1. (3) The data are sent in an unencrypted way. Plain text. That's no good. (not my main problem now, but since I still need to implement it, may be worth addressing it now, rather than later)
2. (5) The login function works, but I don't know how to "communicate" it to React.
3. Even if I manage to pass that information to React (which I think I managed to do it once), how do I keep the state of the logged it user? Like the 'is_authenticated' method, and 'request.user' to see who the active user is?

In top of all of this, I would also require a logout function, if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which method of authentication are you using?

Comment: make login function that accepts username and password; validate if user credentials are correct and if correct return the user_id with success message. Save that user_id in the local storage of react. As long as user is logged in user_id is saved in local storage once the user is logged out clear the user_id from local storage. Hope this helps

Comment: @ShishirSubedi So once I sent the credential to Django and I login in Django, how do I send it back to React? What local storage is for React and how do I use it? Thanks for answering.